# SSH option SecurityKeyProvider works from command line but not config file linux WSL--other options fine

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, configuration, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to ssh into my work server but this bug has been bugging me for a few months now. Every other option in my `config` file (housed at `~/.ssh/config`) works fine, but for some reason SecurityKeyProvider does not. Here's a look:

```
Host [work-server]
     HostName [work-server.work.com]
     SecurityKeyProvider /usr/local/lib/libwindowsfidobridge.so
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
     ServerAliveInterval 60
     ForwardX11Trusted no
     ForwardX11 no
     ForwardAgent no
```

But for some reason I have to run from the command line:
`ssh -o SecurityKeyProvider=/usr/local/lib/libwindowsfidobridge.so me@[work-server.work.com]` instead of just `ssh me@[work-server.work.com]`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski There is no other entry for `SecurityKeyProvider` earlier in the file. That is the full contents of the file. The output of your command is `securitykeyprovider internal`

Comment: What if you use the name from the `Host` line, not from the `HostName` line? `ssh me@[work-server.work.com]` does not match `Host [work-server]`.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

(In this answer I decided not to obfuscate things with `[` and `]` you used.)

`Host work-server` will match if you invoke `ssh work-server` or e.g. `ssh me@work-server`; it will *not* match if you invoke `ssh work-server.work.com` or `ssh me@work-server.work.com`.

The fact you have `HostName work-server.work.com` later in the file is irrelevant. The value of `Host` is what tries to match the host name you used in the command line. `HostName` specifies the real host name to log into, it does not try to match anything.

This means your config was not used upon `ssh me@work-server.work.com`. You wrote "every other option […] works fine", but it was just an illusion because in your config many of the other options are set to their default values anyway, so for them there is no difference between your config working and not working (even `HostName` allegedly worked because its default value is the name given in the command line, and you gave exactly the right name). The problematic `SecurityKeyProvider` turned out to be the first option that made a noticeable difference.

If you find the distinction between `Host` and `HostName` unintuitive, consider the following example:

```
Host foo
  HostName bar
  # config A here
  …

Host baz
  HostName bar
  # config B here
  …
```

`ssh foo` will connect to `bar` using the config A, `ssh baz` will connect to `bar` using the config B (so the whole setup is useful when you want two or more predefined configs for the same host, and you want to easily choose one of them on the fly when invoking `ssh`). `ssh bar` will match neither `Host foo` nor `Host baz`, so it will use neither A nor B. You can add `Host bar` and define a config for `ssh bar` (say, config C); or you can add `bar` to one of the already existing `Host` lines: e.g. if you make the first one `Host foo bar` then both `ssh foo` and `ssh bar` will use the config A (and connect you to `bar` because of `Hostname bar`).

In your case, use `ssh me@work-server`. If you want `ssh work-server.work.com` to *also* use the config, add `work-server.work.com` to the `Host` line:

```
Host work-server work-server.work.com
# the rest of your config here
```